# how to fix tuple error, index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

```
def r_model(input_shape):
  model = Sequential(name="likelihood")
  model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
  model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mae'], optimizer=opt)
  return model

numerical = ['Serial No.', 'GRE Score', 'TOEFL Score', 'University Rating', 'SOP', 'LOR ', 'CGPA', 'Research']  
labels = df['Chance of Admit ']
features = df[numerical]
features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
ct = ColumnTransformer([('standardize', StandardScaler(), numerical)], remainder='passthrough')
features_train = ct.fit_transform(features_train)
features_test = ct.transform(features_test)
```

and this is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 36, in <module>
    features_test = ct.transform(features_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 580, in transform
    if self._n_features > X.shape[1]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

i tried a lot stuff, can't figure it out, it must be simple and obvious, please correct me)

typically it occurs when there's a mismatch between the number of columns specified in the ColumnTransformer and the actual number of columns in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `train_test_split` function returns four separate variables:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y ,
                                   random_state=42, 
                                   test_size=0.25, 
                                   shuffle=True)
```

- You are placing the variables is `wrong order` which causes a mismatch when you try to access `features_test`.
- you need to assign the returned `values` correctly, rearrange the order of `variables`

```
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Comment: thanks for your time. Is shuffle parameter is necessary? or the main problem was only my inattention to order?

Comment: no ,it ain't necessary.